# Alamofire ssl wrong: sessionDeinitialized

Tags: swift, https, certificate, alamofire

I am trying to connect to my https server which use a custom certificate(export on the server .p12 certificate).

Here is my code:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ch-server", ofType: "cer")
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!))
let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data as CFData)!
let pinEvaluator = PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: [certificate], acceptSelfSignedCertificates: true, performDefaultValidation: true, validateHost: true)
let trustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: [CHConstants.ApiHost: pinEvaluator])
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: trustManager)
        
session.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["phone", phone], encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("data:\(response.data)")
    case let .failure(error):
        print("error:\(error)")
    }
}
        
//        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["phone", phone], encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
//            switch response.result {
//            case .success:
//                print(response.data)
//            case let .failure(error):
//                print(error)
//            }
//        }
```

but the response is error:

```
error:sessionDeinitialized
```

Comment: If you want to pin your self signed certificate and you have the `.cer` file in your target, you can reduce the creation of your `pinEvaluator` to something like this: `let pinEvaluator = PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(acceptSelfSignedCertificates: true, performDefaultValidation: false, validateHost: true)`

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your `Session` instance alive. Otherwise it will be immediately deinitialized and your requests cancelled, which is what that error indicates. Most commonly this is done through a singleton or other reference storage pattern.

Comment: Defining a final class and a global variable 'session', then init the class use static. Is it right?

Comment: So many people saying to keep it alive as a singleton - that sounds like a great idea but none of these questions actually explain *how* to do that!

Comment: @whendon There are numerous examples of how to create long lived references like singletons in Swift. I didn't include one here because a singleton may not be what you want for your particular usage. If nothing else, just look at the `AF` instance Alamofire vends to see a single example.